# Use Time.now to get time zoned date in Elm 0.18

Tags: time, utc, elm, elm-0.18

```
posixDateTask : Task.Task x Time.Date.Date
posixDateTask = 
    let
        timeZoneDate now =
            Time.Date.date
                (Time.ZonedDateTime.year (Time.ZonedDateTime.fromDateTime (TimeZones.canada_pacific ()) now))
                (Time.ZonedDateTime.month (Time.ZonedDateTime.fromDateTime (TimeZones.canada_pacific ()) now))
                (Time.ZonedDateTime.day (Time.ZonedDateTime.fromDateTime (TimeZones.canada_pacific ()) now))
    in
    Time.now
        |> Task.map timeZoneDate
```

This gives me an error:

```
    |> Task.map timeZoneDate

(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

     Task.Task x Time.Time -> a

But the right side is:

    Task.Task x Time.DateTime.DateTime -> Task.Task x Time.Date.Date
```

How should I change to return a `Task.Task x Time.Date.Date` type.
I don't know where is the `Time.DateTime.DateTime` come from.

Comment: You can probably do so using a library such as [elm-community/elm-time](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-time/latest/) or [Bogdanp/elm-time](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Bogdanp/elm-time/1.4.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.now` returns a task with a `Time.Time`, which is what you pass to `timeZoneDate` as `now`. You then pass `now` to `Time.ZonedDateTime.fromDateTime`, which expects a `Time.DateTime.DateTime` (which shouldn't be entirely surprising given its name.) You therefore have to convert `now` from `Time.Time` to `Time.DateTime.DateTime`. It seems you can do that using [`Time.DateTime.fromTimestamp`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/elm-time/latest/Time-DateTime#fromTimestamp).

Based on that, something along the liens of this should work:

```
posixDateTask : Task.Task x Time.Date.Date
posixDateTask = 
    let
        timeZoneDate now =
            let
                dateTime =
                    Time.DateTime.fromTimeStamp now

                timeZone =
                    TimeZones.canada_pacific ()

                zonedDateTime =
                    Time.ZonedDateTime.fromDateTime timeZone dateTime
            in
            Time.Date.date
                (Time.ZonedDateTime.year zonedDateTime)
                (Time.ZonedDateTime.month zonedDateTime)
                (Time.ZonedDateTime.day zonedDateTime)
    in
    Time.now
        |> Task.map timeZoneDate
```